# Wildcard SSL certificate error

Tags: ssl

I installed a wildcard SSL certificate, but somehow I ended up with an error.

When accessing the website I am getting:

> The identity of this website has not been verified.
>   • Server's certificate does not match the URL.
>   • Server's certificate is not trusted.

The CN is like *.domain.com
and that goes with all the subdomains, too. I think I am missing something and that's why this is not working.

crt file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: This is a very poor question, it doesn't even show the certificate. I'll answer it because it seems like an obvious beginner mistake but in the future please try to add relevant information

Comment: Look at the certificate the browser is getting and see if it's the one you're expecting.

Comment: crt file added, sorry for the delay

Comment: Your certificate works, if you want to not have scary warnings then you can go and buy a signed one from a trusted CA. You can't use self-signed certificates and expect them to be trusted on the internet.

Comment: it was the problem of the certificate conflict, now working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Either you are not serving the correct certificate or you're trying to browse `domain.com`.

If your CN is `*.domain.com`, then browsing to `domain.com` will not work. `*.domain.com` does NOT mean `*.com`. One way to make it work is to have `domain.com` as the CN, and `*.domain.com` as the subjectAlternateName. This kind of certificate will be valid for both straight `domain.com` and all subdomains.

"Is not trusted" is caused by you not trusting the certificate. This is a self-signed certificate, trusting it in your favorite browser or OS store will work. On Firefox, this means adding an exception.

Comment: please check the crt file

Comment: That certificate will be valid for any subdomain under .uttamschool.net, but not for uttamschool.net. It is flagged as a CA certificate though which is weird.

Comment: check geo.uttamschool.net

Comment: geo.uttamschool.net works just fine when you trust the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is self-signed.  That's the only error I get when connecting to https://geo.uttamschool.net/, and it's an entirely correct error.  I'm not, therefore, entirely sure what the problem is.